# How do I use a common, custom DateTimeFormat in GWT in different locales?

Tags: date, gwt, internationalization

We have a calendar widget which accepts a few date formats. We would like to add the format 'MM-dd-yyyy' for US-based clients. But in other locales, this format could be interpreted as 'dd-MM-yyyy' (or other interpretations). The [docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsFormatting.html) say to "use the default formats and let the localization mechanism in the DateTimeFormat do the work for you."

Would CustomDateTimeFormat be my solution? I've looked at it, but the usage is unclear and the docs almost non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `PredefinedFormat.DATE_MEDIUM` would do what you want, e.g.:

```
DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_MEDIUM);
```

The date format will change according to the GWT locale.

By the way, the examples provided in the doc that you linked to are using a deprecated syntax. It has been replaced by `PredefinedFormat`.

Comment: No, DATE_MEDIUM is format 'Mar 16, 1973'; I'm looking for 3-16-73 or 3-16-1973

Comment: Did you try with `PredefinedFormat.DATE_SHORT`?

Comment: Yes, but PredefinedFormat.DATE_SHORT uses slashes (3/16/73), not dashes